# Why can I call a private method of another instance of the same type outside of that instance?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

If I have ObjectA, and it has a private method `GetPrice()` and also has a "parent" field of the same type, why am I able to call `GetPrice()` on the parent instance from within the child instance?

Example:

```
private decimal GetPrice()
{
    ObjectA parent = Parent;

    if(parent != null)
    {
        return parent.GetPrice(); // Why is this OK?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the language designers thought it should work that way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because private means "not accessible to other *types*", not "not accessible to other *instances*".

Comment: Thanks...In the 5 years I've been programming C#, I never noticed this. I guess from the time I learned C#'s access modifiers, I mistook it as being private to the instance. Now I feel like a fool. Ya learn something every day!

Comment: @Ryan, I know what you mean... I guess this is one of those things you can "misunderstand" for a long time. And basically it behaves just like you'd think, until you actually *try* to access another instance's private member and realise that it's allowed :)

Comment: This is quite surprising to me. Is there any literature that describes *why* it is like this?

Answer (score 6):

Because `private` scope is limited to the *class*, not the *instance* as defined in the [C# spec](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552):

> 1.6.2 Accessibility
>   Each member of a class has an associated accessibility, which controls
>   the regions of program text that are able to access the member. There
>   are five possible forms of accessibility. These are summarized in the
>   following table.
>
> ```
> Accessibility       Meaning   
>
> public              Access not limited   
> protected           Access limited to this class or classes derived from this class  
> internal            Access limited to this program   
> protected internal  Access limited to this program or classes derived from this class    
> private             Access limited to this class
> ```

Answer (score 1):

An access modifier is related to it's implementing class/type not to instances of that class